# How to add lot of wavepoints in .gpx file?

Tags: gps, gpx

I want to add more wave points in the gpx file. I tried to create from google maps but not getting much of wave points. How can I add them?

Answer (score 0):

To add the gpx files to project you can manually create gpx files and add them to your projects.

Alternatively you can create more gpx files using the following xcode plugin:

https://github.com/StefanLage/XLocation